# How can we temporarily turn off the running website & give a message "This site is Temprorary unavailable"

Tags: asp.net

How can we temporary off the running website & gives a message "This site is Temprorary unavailable", actully i want to gives a power to admin he can temporary on/Off the website...
according to my need i dnt want to add web_offline.htm page. I simply do it by button control i.e. Active website & Deactive website(dynamic method)

Answer (score 5):

Place `app_offline.htm` page **on root of your asp.net website**.

The user then see what ever you have write on this `app_offline.htm` file.

For more detail http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx

Comment: Okk thanks for your reply Irfan... but according to my need i dnt want to add web_offline.htm page. I simply  do it by button control i.e. Active website & Deactive website(dynamic method).

Comment: Ok then it can be possible via utilizing global.asax begine request event. when user click stop button, you need to set e.g application set which should be check with each user request. if on then user should be redirect to temp unavailable page.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for this:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx

Basically just create an app_offline.htm file and your application will shutdown and users will get that page.

Comment: Okk thanks for your reply RexM... but according to my need i dnt want to add web_offline.htm page. I simply  do it by button control i.e. Active website & Deactive website(dynamic method).